# How do I show a 500 error stack trace to admins only on production in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, internal-server-error

I want it so that ordinary users see the normal "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message when they hit a 500 error but admins see the development style full stack trace on production.

We are using exceptional but it's also helpful to be able to debug errors inline on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it before but I think you could have a before_filter in your ApplicationController which would check if the user is an admin and if so, do something to this effect:

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
end
```